# Firefox OS 'HELLO WORLD' development

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-os

i want to develop apps for Firefox-OS but i simply cant understand where to start from. Okay i have firefox Os simulator installed, i got my notepad open, I know html 5, css3, JS, jQuery bla bla bla...I googled but simply couldnt find the tutorial for HELLO WORLD FIREFOX OS app. any help guys. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://shafiul.github.io/slides/kickstart_fxos.html#/16) took me about a minute to find. A step by step guide. More info related to app development for FF OS can be found at their [official page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Apps)

Edit: A [video tutorial](http://popcorn.webmadecontent.org/9wp) with the use of the jQuery library.

Comment: thanks :) i too found it in the mean time..i looked here and there in the developer section of firfox OS..he he he... and thanks for the VDO tutorial...really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

As far as "Hello World!"-type of beginner-applications concerned, I think [`fxosstub`](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/fxosstub-a-minimalists-working-example-of-the-design-guide-rules-for-firefox-os/) is as close as it gets. Also as you will most definitely want to work with some of the [Open Web API-s](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI), so I'd recommend studying Robert Nyman's [Firefox OS Boilerplate App](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/01/introducing-the-firefox-os-boilerplate-app/), which itself, is based on the above mentioned `fxosstub` application, and is a great way to learn a thing or two about the Open Web API-s and about accessing the mobile device hardware through JavaScript API calls in Firefox OS.

Those two articles mentioned both appeared on [Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/), mozilla's developer blog, which is treasure trove of - among other things - [Firefox OS related articles and resources](https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/firefox-os/). Another great place to start would be the [Quick start guide](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/quick_start) in the Developer section of the [Firefox Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/).

For technical reference you should check out the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) - it contains a host of very useful information about [Web Applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps), [Web API-s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) and general web development, too.

For Firefox OS UI-design samples, resources & best practices you might want to check out the [Mozilla Brick Library](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/introducing-brick-minimal-markup-web-components-for-faster-app-development/) (a successor to the former [Building Firefox OS](http://buildingfirefoxos.com/) website) if you want your app to blend in visually with the core applications in Firefox OS.

Also there is a pretty active community at the [Mozilla webapps mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozilla.dev.webapps) where you might find lots of helpful chaps, well-versed in the intricacies of Firefox OS, and would gladly help you out whenever you might find yourself stuck during development.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [BMI calculator webapp](https://github.com/gasolin/FxOSBMI) that follow Firefox OS build-in apps (Gaia) structure and use Firefox OS build-in styles. Check the [demo](http://gasolin.github.io/fxosbmi/public/index.html) to see how real hosted webapp looks like on any device.

(For a web platform, you can use whatever you are familiar with, but BMI calculator is a kind of hello world type app though...)

Or here is the [webapplate](http://github.com/gasolin/webapplate) project, which has preconfigured webapp template for hosted or package
 reuse. [BMI calculator webapp](https://github.com/gasolin/FxOSBMI) is modified from that.

(Note Firefox OS build-in styles are not cross-browser friendly yet. )

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answers are a bit out of date. I think the fastest/easiest way to start development is to

1) Download [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) and start it up

2) From Firefox developer edition, launch the WebIDE (click on the little spanner, and choose WebIDE). From there you can create a hello world application.

For more information see the [WebIDE documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE)