# Which is the best framework to develop for Firefox Os

Tags: frameworks, firefox-os

I am trying to develop in Firefox Os, but which is the best (fast, structured) framework for that. I try with Sencha Touch, but unfortunately It doesn't work with firefox yet.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All frontend frameworks that support Firefox work on FxOS. AngularJS, Backbone, etc should bring you the view abstraction you need.

More options are being released, like [Lungo](http://lungo.tapquo.com/), an HTML5 app and component framework. jQuery Mobile is another UI-component framework working well on Firefox OS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried with Sencha but It doesn't support yet and I have developed with JQuery Mobile for Android, but I didn't try it for firefox Os. I will take your opinions. Lungo sounds interesting at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that - at the moment - there are no fast/all-in-one mobile application framework solutions, that already support Firefox OS development. PhoneGap [in a recent blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/06/20/coming-soon-phonegap30/) announced, that PhoneGap support for *"Firefox OS and Ubuntu are coming soon."* - but it's not there yet.*

I would recommend trying the conventional approach, and building an app from scratch, the resources discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503498/1178775) should help in that.

*Update: As of March 4th, 2014 version 3.4+ of the PhoneGap framework [does indeed support building for Firefox OS](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/03/04/phonegap-3-4-release/)*

Comment: yeah Phonegap is awesome!!! I developed with that. It is a good news, but that you told me there isn't anything yet. Thanks a lot for sharing me the links

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to App-development, but, for what it's worth, I would recommend Enyo. With this framework you can develop 'platform-agnostic' apps, and also Firefox OS is supported: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/03/firefox-os-support-lands-in-enyojs-2-2/

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Sencha Touch (2.3.1) does support firefox, and also Internet Explorer. Maybe you could take another look at Sencha Touch.