# Firefox OS : Getting Started Tutorial

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I want to start development in Firefox OS . So I want some blog tutorials or video tutorials for getting started. Sample code also will be sufficient.

Comment: Do you accept french blog ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, learn what a manifest file is(provided that you already know JS, CSS and HTML5 technologies): [App Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Manifest)

Then grab the Firefox OS simulator addon for Firefox(latest release - stable/unstable) and do as the MDN says. That's it!

I ported my HTML5 game to Firefox OS without that much tweaking, it's so easy! Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I have written a series of tutorials on the Firefox OS. Please find the entire series over here: http://rominirani.com/category/mobile-2/firefox-os/

Answer (score 1):

Follow http://buildingfirefoxos.com/. It's the best place to build apps for Firefox OS

Answer (score 0):

here is the best tutorial for starting firefox os development, with hello world sample application.
http://freezinfo.com/firefox-os-basic-tutorial-hello-world-application/

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503498/1178775) for a quite comprehensive list on where to start developing for Firefox OS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a screencast series called [Firefox OS App Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Screencast_series:_App_Basics_for_Firefox_OS) by Christian Heilmann, Sergi Mansilla and me.